# How can I change the number of rows displayed by ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datagrid, scrollbar, ng-grid

Im using ng-grid to display some data. Currently ng-grid is displaying around 10 rows of data before the vertical scroll bar kicks in and hides the rest. How can I change the threshold for the vertical scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

This depends of your rowHeight and the headerHeight of your grid.

With default values by 30px for both values you can adjust the total gridHeight in the CSS with:

```
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 400px; 
    height: 482px
}
```

(2px added for borders.)

Also you want to disable the overflow for the viewport:

```
.ngViewport {
    min-height: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

That what you wanted?

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UE2M7A?p=preview) with 15 rows (hence 15*30px of rows + 30px of header + 2px borders = 482px gridHeight)

Comment: Almost. I still want the scrollbar to appear, just after a larger number of rows.

Comment: Then leave out the ngViewport css rule and leave overflow to default auto. In this Plunker you can add new rows to myData by clicking the button and see how the scrollbar reappears. You still have to fiddle a bit with the css. That's the best I can do. The calculations of widths and heights in ng-grid always seemed to be a bit buggy. I don't think that can be changed with a 1-line patch in the source. Maybe look at the new ui-grid (which is ng-grid in it's 3.x version).